Illustrated children's book about a man falling in love with a red-head witch
Here's what I can remember: There is a man, maybe a huntsman or something. He travels into the woods and find three witches living in a cave. I remember an illustration with the man hiding in the brush and the thee witches all stirring a cauldron outside the mouth of the cave (I think I am remembering it correctly?). Two of the witches are older, but the third is young with a mass of fiery red hair and I remember she always looked angry or grumpy.
The man falls in love with the young red-head witch. I think he comes back several times to watch them come out of the cave and stir their cauldron. At some point, either he approaches the other two witches or they catch him or something. They agree to help him with a love potion to make the young with fall for him. I remember it being a little cake, like a moon cake-looking thing. I honestly don't remember the end.
I read this as a young child sometime in the 90s. I want to say it was the same time that I had books like Buried Moon (Margaret Hodges) and Whale's Song (Sheldon, Blythe) so early-mid 90s. The illustrations (in my memory) are pretty legit too, kind of like Buried Moon caliber, not quite that style, but realism and full page.
